# Raytracing sphere diffuse reflection bug

Tags: javascript, vector, raytracing

I made this ray tracer in JavaScript to run on HTML with imageData. I have been using the book "[Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html)" as a reference  and I am on the step where I create a diffuse material (essentially the surfaces with diffuse materials pick up the color of another object through randomly generated rays in a recursive process) Apparently, the diffuse material works on the plane I created but it doesn't work on the sphere. All the normal calculations work fine on the sphere and it does seem to respond to light a little bit but the color returned appears to be the same for the entire sphere. What are possible explanations for this kind of bug? I have attached the runnable js code snippet below.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("viewport");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var h = cvs.height;
var w = cvs.width;
var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0, w, h);
var scene ={};
//object for all the stuff and parameters in the scene
scene.skybox = {
  color: {
    x:150,
    y:200,
    z:250,
  }
}
scene.camera = {
    point: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 10,
    },
    fieldOfView: 45,
    vector: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
    },
  };

scene.lights = [
  {
    point:{
      x: 0,
      y: -5,
      z: 0,
    },
    j:50,
  },
  // {
  //   x:5,
  //   y:-5,
  //   z:-5,
  // }
]; 
scene.objects = [
    {
      type: "sphere",
      point: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
      },
      color: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
      },
      radius: 1,
      ambient:0,
      lambert:0.5,
      specular:0,
      diffuse:0,
    },
    {
      type: "plane",
      point: {
        x: 0,
        y: 1,
        z: 0,
      },
      vector:{
        x:0,
        y:-1,
        z:0,
      },
      color: {
        x: 255,
        y: 255,
        z: 255,
      },
      ambient:0,
      lambert:0.5,
      specular:0,
      diffuse:0,
    },
    // {
    //   type: "triangle",
    //   a:{x:3,y:1,z:-3},
    //   b:{x:-2,y:0,z:-2},
    //   c:{x:2,y:-2,z:-2},
    //   color:{
    //     x:0,
    //     y:100,
    //     z:100
    //   },
    //   ambient:0.1,
    //   lambert:1,
    //   specular:0,
    // },
  ];
window.onload=init();
function init(){
  var left_arrow = 37;
  var right_arrow = 39;
  var up_arrow = 38;
  var down_arrow = 40;
  var w_key = 87;
  var a_key = 65;
  var s_key = 83;
  var d_key = 68;
  render();
  window.onkeydown= function(gfg){
    if(gfg.keyCode === a_key){
      scene.camera.point.x-=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === d_key)
    {
      scene.camera.point.x+=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === w_key){
      scene.camera.point.y-=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === s_key)
    {
      scene.camera.point.y+=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === left_arrow){
      scene.lights[0].point.z+=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === right_arrow)
    {
      scene.lights[0].point.z-=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === up_arrow){
      scene.lights[0].point.x-=1;
      render();
    };
    if(gfg.keyCode === down_arrow)
    {
      scene.lights[0].point.x+=1;
      render();
    };
  };
}
function render(){
  var start = performance.now();
  var camera = scene.camera;
  var eVec = unitVector(subtract(camera.vector, camera.point));
  var eVecRight = unitVector(crossProduct(eVec, {x:0, y:1, z:0}));
  var eVecUp = unitVector(crossProduct(eVecRight, eVec));
  var halfFOV = (Math.PI * (camera.fieldOfView / 2)) / 180;
  var halfW = Math.tan(halfFOV);
  var halfH = (h/w)*halfW;
  var W = halfW*2;
  var H = halfH*2;
  var Wpx = W/(w-1);
  var Hpx = H/(h-1);
  var index;
  var spx = 50;
  var ray = {
      point: camera.point,
  };
  for (var i=0; i<scene.objects.length; i++){
    var object = scene.objects[i];
    if (object.type == "plane"){
      object.vector = unitVector(object.vector);
    }else if (object.type == "triangle"){
      object.vector = unitVector(crossProduct(subtract(object.b, object.a),subtract(object.c,object.a)));
    }
  }
  for (var x =0; x<w; x++){
      for(var y =0; y<h; y++){
        var color = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
        for (var i=0; i<spx; i++){
          var xcomp = scaleVector(eVecRight, (x+Math.random()) * Wpx - halfW);
          var ycomp = scaleVector(eVecUp, (y+Math.random()) * Hpx - halfH);
          ray.vector = unitVector(add3Vectors(eVec, xcomp, ycomp));
          color = addVectors(gamma(scaleVector(trace(ray, scene, 2), 1/spx)),color);
        }
        // console.log(color);
        index = (y*w+x)*4;
        data.data[index]=clamp(color.x, 0, 255);
        data.data[index+1]=clamp(color.y, 0, 255);
        data.data[index+2]=clamp(color.z, 0, 255);
        data.data[index+3]=255;
      }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(data, 0,0);
  var end = performance.now();
  console.log(end-start);
}

function trace(ray, scene, iter){
  // if(iter>3) return;
  var distObj = SceneIntersect(ray, scene);
  // if (distObj[0] === Infinity){
  //   return scene.skybox.color;
  // }else{
  //   pointOfIntersect = addVectors(scene.camera.point, scaleVector(ray.vector, distObj[0]));
  //   return surface(ray, scene, distObj[1], pointOfIntersect, iter);
  // }
  if (distObj[0] === Infinity){
    var pointOfIntersect = null;
  }else{
    var pointOfIntersect = addVectors(scene.camera.point, scaleVector(ray.vector, distObj[0]));
  }
  // console.log(distObj);
  return surface(ray, scene, distObj[1], pointOfIntersect, iter);
  // return {x:distObj[0]*10, y:0, z:0};
}

function SceneIntersect(ray, scene){
  var closest = [Infinity, null];
  for (var i=0; i<scene.objects.length; i++){
    var object = scene.objects[i];
    if (object.type == "sphere"){
      var dist = raySphereIntersect(object, ray);
    }else if(object.type == "plane"){
      var dist = rayPlaneIntersect(object, ray);
    }else if(object.type == "triangle"){
      var dist = rayTriangleIntersect(object,ray);
    }
    if (dist !== undefined && dist < closest[0]){
      closest = [dist, object];
    }
  }
  return closest;
}

function isLightVisible(pt, scene, light) {
  var distObject = SceneIntersect(
    {
      point: pt,
      vector: unitVector(subtract(pt, light)),
    },
    scene
  );
  return distObject[0] > -0.005;
}

function gamma(a){
  return {
    x:Math.sqrt(a.x),
    y:Math.sqrt(a.y),
    z:Math.sqrt(a.z),
  };
}
function dotProduct(a,b){
    return a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y+a.z*b.z;
}

function unitVector(a){
    m = Math.sqrt(dotProduct(a,a));
    return {
        x: a.x/m,
        y: a.y/m,
        z: a.z/m
    };
}

function scaleVector(a, m){
  return {
    x:a.x*m,
    y:a.y*m,
    z:a.z*m
  }
}

function subtract(a,b){
    return {
        x: a.x- b.x,
        y: a.y- b.y,
        z: a.z - b.z
    };
}

function crossProduct(a,b){
    return {
       x: a.y*b.z-a.z*b.y,
       y: a.z*b.x-a.x*b.z,
       z: a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x
    };
}

function add3Vectors(a,b,c){
  return {
    x:a.x+b.x+c.x,
    y:a.y+b.y+c.y,
    z:a.z+b.z+c.z
  }
}

function addVectors(a,b){
  return{
    x:a.x+b.x,
    y:a.y+b.y,
    z:a.z+b.z
  }
}

function reflect(a,n){
  return subtract(scaleVector(n, 2*dotProduct(n,a)),a);
}

function clamp(x, min, max){
  if(x<min) return min;
  if (x>max) return max;
  return x;
}

// function raySphereIntersect(sphere, ray){
//     var ec = subtract(ray.point, sphere.point);
//     // var v = dotProduct(ray.vector, ec);
//     // var ecDot = dotProduct(ec, ec);
//     // var s2 = sphere.radius * sphere.radius - ecDot + v*v;
//     var a = dotProduct(ray.vector, ray.vector);
//     var b = dotProduct(ec, ray.vector);
//     var c = dotProduct(ec, ec) - sphere.radius*sphere.radius;
//     var d = b*b -a*c;
//     if (d <0){
//         return;
//     }else{
//         // var dist = v - Math.sqrt(s2);
//         var dist = (-b-Math.sqrt(d))/a;
//         // return v - Math.sqrt(s2);
//         // return (-b-Math.sqrt(d))/a;
//         // console.log(dist);
//         return dist;
//     }
// }

// function raySphereIntersect(sphere, ray){
//   var oc = subtract(ray.point, sphere.point);
//   var p = dotProduct(ray.vector, oc);
//   var q = dotProduct(oc, oc) - sphere.radius*sphere.radius;
//   var d = (p*p)-q;
//   if (d<0){
//     return;
//   }else{
//     var droot = Math.sqrt(d);
//     d1 = -p-droot;
//     // d2 = -p+droot;
//     return d1;
//   }
// }

function raySphereIntersect(sphere, ray){
  var ec = subtract(sphere.point, ray.point);
  var v = dotProduct(ray.vector, ec);
  var ecDot = dotProduct(ec, ec);
  var s2 = sphere.radius * sphere.radius - ecDot + v*v;
  // console.log(s2);
  if (s2 <0){
      return;
  }else{
      return v - Math.sqrt(s2);
  }
}

function rayPlaneIntersect(plane, ray){
  // var npNormal = unitVector(scaleVector(subtract(plane.vector, plane.point),-1));
  // var ep = subtract(plane.point, ray.point);
  // var a = dotProduct(npNormal,ep);
  // var u = scaleVector(npNormal, a);
  // var v = dotProduct(ray.vector, u);
  // var d = (a*a)/v;
  var n = unitVector(plane.vector);
  var d = dotProduct(n,subtract(plane.point,ray.point))/dotProduct(ray.vector,n);
  if (d<0){
    return;
  }else{
    return d;
  }
}

function rayTriangleIntersect(triangle, ray){
  var a = triangle.a,
  b = triangle.b,
  c = triangle.c;
  var n = triangle.vector;
  var d = dotProduct(n,subtract(a,ray.point))/dotProduct(ray.vector,n);
  var p = addVectors(ray.point,scaleVector(ray.vector,d));
  if (dotProduct(n,crossProduct(subtract(b,a),subtract(p,a)))>=0 &&
      dotProduct(n,crossProduct(subtract(c,b),subtract(p,b)))>=0 &&
      dotProduct(n,crossProduct(subtract(a,c),subtract(p,c)))>=0){
    return d;
  }else{
    return;
  }
}

function surface(ray, scene, object, p, iter){
  var tLambert=0;
  var tSpecular = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
  var tDiffuse = {x:0,y:0,z:0};
  // var c = object.color;
  // if(object.lambert>0){
  //   for (var i = 0; i<scene.lights.length; i++){
  //     var lightPoint = scene.lights[i].point;
  //     if (!isLightVisible(p, scene, lightPoint))continue;
  //     var r2 = dotProduct(subtract(lightPoint,p), subtract(lightPoint, p));
  //     var toLight = unitVector(subtract(lightPoint,p));
  //     // var intensity = dotProduct(toLight,unitVector(addVectors(normal,scaleVector(subtract(randSphere(p, normal), p),0.5))));
  //     var intensity = (scene.lights[i].j/r2)*dotProduct(toLight, normal);
  //     if (intensity>0) tLambert+=intensity;
  //   }
  // }
  // if(object.diffuse >0){
  //   var target = randSphere(p, normal);
  //   var rColor = trace({point:p, vector: unitVector(subtract(target, p))}, scene, ++iter);
  //   console.log(rColor);
  //   if(rColor){
  //     tDiffuse = addVectors(tDiffuse, scaleVector(rColor, object.diffuse));
  //   }else{
  //     tDiffuse = addVectors(scaleVector(scene.skybox.color,0.5),tDiffuse);
  //   }
  //   // console.log(tDiffuse);
  // }
  // if(object.specular>0){
  //   var rRay = {point: p, vector: reflect(ray.vector, normal)}
  //   // var rRay = {point:p, vector: unitVector(subtract(randSphere(p, normal), p))};
  //   var rColor = trace(rRay, scene, ++iter);
  //   if(rColor){
  //     tSpecular = addVectors(tSpecular, scaleVector(rColor,object.specular));
  //   }
  // }
  // return add3Vectors(
  //   scaleVector(c, tLambert*object.lambert),
  //   tSpecular,
  //   scaleVector(c, object.ambient)
  // );
  if (iter <= -1) {
    // console.log("yo")
    // return {x:255,y:0,z:0};
    return scene.skybox.color;
  }
  if (p == null){
    return scene.skybox.color;
  }else{
    if (object.type == "sphere"){
      // console.log(object);
      var normal = sphereNormal(object, p, ray);
      var target = add3Vectors(p, normal, randSphere());
      // return scaleVector(scaleVector(addVectors(normal, {x:1,y:1,z:1}),0.5),255);
      // console.log(Math.sqrt(dotProduct(subtract(p,object.point),subtract(p,object.point))));
      // return {x:subtract(p,object.point), y:0, z:0};
      return scaleVector(trace({point:p, vector: unitVector(subtract(target, p))}, scene, --iter), 0.5);
      // console.log(normal);
    }else{
      var normal = object.vector;
      var target = add3Vectors(p, normal, randSphere());
      // return {x:255*normal.x,y:255*normal.y, z:255*normal.z};
      return scaleVector(trace({point:subtract(p,{x:0.005, y:0.005, z:0.005}), vector: unitVector(subtract(target, p))}, scene, --iter), 0.5);
    }
  }
}

function sphereNormal(sphere, p, ray){
  var normal = scaleVector(subtract(p, sphere.point), 1/sphere.radius);
  var front = dotProduct(ray.vector, normal) < 0;
  // console.log(front);
  normal = front ? normal : scaleVector(normal, -1);
  return normal;
}

function randSphere(){
  var a = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
  var b = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
  var x = Math.sin(a)*Math.cos(b);
  var y = Math.sin(a)*Math.sin(b);
  var z = Math.cos(a);
  return {x:x,y:y,z:z};
}

// function test2() {
//   var start = performance.now();
//   for (var i=0; i<100000; i++){
//     do {
//       var d, x, y, z;
//       x = Math.random() * 2.0 - 1.0;
//       y = Math.random() * 2.0 - 1.0;
//       z = Math.random() * 2.0 - 1.0;
//       d = x*x + y*y + z*z;
//     } while(d > 1.0);
//   }
//   var end = performance.now();
//   return end-start;
// }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>raytracing</title>
    <canvas id='viewport' width = '256' height = '256'></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```